# How to Multisort a list of objects based on given settings?

Tags: c#, sorting

The goal : you have a list of objects, you want the end user to be able to choose some objects properties to define a sort and choose sort direction for each property.

Let's take this Node object as an example:

```
    public class Node
    {
        public int CustomProperty { get; set; }
        public string CustomStringProperty { get; set; }

        public string id;
        public string parentId;
        public string Speed;
        public int WheelNumber;
        public int SeatNumber;

        public List<Node> Child { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Child = new List<Node>();
        }
    }
```

Let's say you have a list of Node you want to sort based on criterias such as speed, wheelnumber or seat number.

You will use whatever .OrderBy, .ThenByDescending and so on based on goal but the problem is it's hard coded so it's the developer who is currently managing code; the end user won't dive into code, even less each time he needs to change the criterias collection for sorting and define direction for each criteria (object property).

You could use some code helping the user to define preferences, something like this :

```
public static List<Node> Sort(List<Node> nodes, int level, string[] sortingPreferences)
    {
        // Recursively sort nodes children
        foreach (var node in nodes)
            node.Child = Sort(node.Child, level + 1, sortingPreferences);

           // Now sort the nodes based on preference
            if (nodes.Count < 2) return nodes;

            if (level < sortingPreferences.Length)
            {
                switch (sortingPreferences[level])
                {
                    case "SPEED": return nodes.OrderBy(node => node.Speed).ToList();
                    case "WHEEL_NUMBER": return nodes.OrderBy(node => node.WheelNumber).ToList();
                    case "SEAT_NUMBER": return nodes.OrderBy(node => node.SeatNumber).ToList();
                    case "SPEED - WHEEL_NUMBER": return nodes.OrderBy(node => node.Speed).ThenBy(node => node.WheelNumber).ToList();
                    case "SPEED - WHEEL_NUMBER - SEAT_NUMBER": return nodes.OrderBy(node => node.Speed).ThenBy(node => node.WheelNumber).ThenByDescending(node => node.SeatNumber).ToList();
                    // And so on...
                    // And so on...
                }
            }
            // Unchanged (or nodes.OrderBy(some default order)
            return nodes;
    }
```

This code example is just here to illustrate the idiot approach in there, ie you won't cover all criterias combinations to define your multisort to apply on a list of objects and then extend this combination process to cover also directions for each of the criterias used.

The question is  : How to define some sort settings/preferences in which criterias (speed, wheel number, seat number...) would be applied, along with their related sort direction, on a list of object to multisort it ?

I mean, for example, preferences could be given this way :

```
        new List<string>[]
                    {
                       new List<string>{ "SPEED", "ASCENDING" },           
                       new List<string>{ "WHEEL_NUMBER", "DESCENDING" },           
                       new List<string>{ "SEAT_NUMBER", "DESCENDING" },
                    },
```

Here you have 3 criterias but the end user, through a gui, could add some more and choose direction for each of them.

Then, how to take these preferences into account to apply them on the list of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary of delegates to supply your query with OrderBy clauses. Each delegate must accept an object and return the value to sort on.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<Node,IComparable>>
{
    { "PropertyA", node => node.PropertyA },
    { "PropertyB", node => node.PropertyB }
};
```

Then put your sorting keys into an array as well:

```
var sortBy = new string[] { "PropertyA", "PropertyB" };
```

Once you have that in order, you can sort with a simple loop by looking up the delegate for each key. You have to reverse the order of keys, since the each key processed will take precedence over the previous keys.

```
foreach (var sortKey in sortBy.Reverse())
{
    list = list.OrderBy( map[sortKey] );
}
```

Here's how it looks in context with test data:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,Func<Node,IComparable>>
{
    { "PropertyA", node => node.PropertyA },
    { "PropertyB", node => node.PropertyB }
};

IEnumerable<Node> list = new Node[]
{
    new Node { PropertyA = 1, PropertyB = "Z" },
    new Node { PropertyA = 2, PropertyB = "A" },
    new Node { PropertyA = 2, PropertyB = "B" }
};


var sortBy = new string[] { "PropertyA", "PropertyB" };

foreach (var sortKey in sortBy.Reverse())
{
    list = list.OrderBy( map[sortKey] );
}

foreach (var node in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", node.PropertyA, node.PropertyB);
}
```

Output:

```
1 Z
2 A
2 B
```

[Working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8mYgKu)

Comment: Hi John, many thanks for these details up to a working complete example in Fiffle, thay's really great ! 
Testing with value 1 on all PropertyA => the data set is well sorted on PropertyB so the sorting on the next property has influence on the data set but less than the previous property sort criteria which is the goal!
About the sort direction per criteria, i feel i miss something; i see "OrderBy" in your code, like if we sort only ascending whatever the property, ie i don't see how/where we declare : "ok, i want PropertyA to be descending while PropertyB has to be ascending and so on".

Comment: I don't see any indication of descending sort being possible in your example. How would indicate this in `sortingPreferences[]`?

Comment: It could like in my last example  :  `new List<string>[]
                    {
                       new List<string>{ "SPEED", "ASCENDING" },           
                       new List<string>{ "WHEEL_NUMBER", "DESCENDING" },           
                       new List<string>{ "SEAT_NUMBER", "DESCENDING" },
                    }`, or with another structure you may like in which you mention the direction for a property.

Comment: If the format of the input is still open to design, why not pass a delegate? Inventing your own data structure to represent a sort operation is unnecessary when c# already provides one (that is extensible and type-safe)..

Comment: Thank you John, yes good suggestion, the code is still open to design. What would be the code for that ? Please do not delete the actual one as it's a good working solution but also interested if you think it's better to do differently by having another code.

Comment: Yes, i'm open to your design idea, please share your thought

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `OrderBy` calls into `ICommands` (command pattern). First you build a commands queue where each command returns a collection, then you loop over the commands queue. If your input changes the `commandslist` has to be rebuilt.

You can use a *fifo* queue to store the commands and when an command should be removed you just dequeue until you find the command to be removed while keeping all dequeued commands to then enqueue them minus the removed command back to the queue.

Edit: you can use c# Func for the commands and a queue of keyvaluepair sorting enum and Func.

`Func<List<T>,List<T>>`  for example and `Queue<KeyValuePair<SortEnum,Func<List<T>,List<T>>>`

Comment: Hi Felipe, thank you for this proposition, i feel something good is in it but as i'm a newbie in C#, i must admit i'm a little lost, trying to understand every corners and to transpose that in code. Thanks anyway.